# How can I get strpos() to distinguish between '1' and '10' in a string?

Tags: php

I have PHP code that changes the page title depending on a query string within a URL. However, this query string is formed by an incrementing number, and when it includes the number 10 (or 11, 12, etc.) then it uses the number 1's variables instead. Is there any way for strpos to see if/that there's a difference?

Snippet:

```
<?php
$fullurl = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$title = "";
$meta = "";

if (strpos($fullurl,'planes-trains-automobiles') !== false) {
    if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=1') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 1";
        $meta = "Meta 1";
    }
    else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=2') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 2";
        $meta = "Meta 2";

    }
...
else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=10') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 10";
        $meta = "Meta 10";

    }
```

Example:

http://myurl-here.com?mag=10 gives me `Title 1` not `Title 10`.

Comment: Yet another url parser? Discover regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the answer as such, your problem can be simply resolved by reordering your IF/ELSE clauses so that you check for 10, 11... before you check for 1:

```
<?php
if (strpos($fullurl,'planes-trains-automobiles') !== false) {
    if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=10') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 10";
        $meta = "Meta 10";
    }
    else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=11') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 11";
        $meta = "Meta 11";

    }
...
    else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=1') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 1";
        $meta = "Meta 1";   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use $_GET['mag']. To be secure, you could check if it is an integer either by

```
$is_valid = is_numeric($_GET['mag']) && is_int(1*$_GET['mag']);
```

or

```
$is_valid = preg_match('/^[\d]+$/',$_GET['mag']);
```

So you would do:

```
if ($is_valid):
     die('wow so insecure, maybe');
else:
     //do whatever you want with $_GET['mag']
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't work by string matching a full URL, work with the *parsed* values! For the current request all you need to do is use `$_GET['mag']`.

```
if (isset($_GET['mag']) && ctype_digit($_GET['mag'])) {
    $title = 'Title ' . $_GET['mag'];
    $meta  = 'Meta ' . $_GET['mag'];
}
```

Or possibly:

```
$titles = array(
    1 => 'Title 1',
    2 => 'Title 2',
    ...
);

if (isset($titles[$_GET['mag']])) {
    $title = $titles[$_GET['mag']];
}
```

Or:

```
switch ($_GET['mag']) {
    case 1 :
       ...
    case 2 :
       ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not extract the number with `preg_match`?

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $url, $m);
$title = "Title ".$m[0];
```

will match

```
$url= 'http://myurl-here.com?mag=10';
$url= 'http://myurl-here.com?mag=1';
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=10') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 10";
        $meta = "Meta 10";
    }
    else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=1') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 1";
        $meta = "Meta 1";
    }
    else if (strpos($fullurl,'mag=2') !== false) {
        $title = "Title 2";
        $meta = "Meta 2";
    }
```

This way the if never reaches mag=1, if mag=10 (11, 12 etc, if placed before 1) has already been selected.

Comment: Why vote down this answer? I (and user1853181) answered the asked question, which was: "Is there any way for strpos to see if/that there's a difference?"